# twig {% image string %} with concated string

Tags: symfony, twig

I have code like that

```
{% for i in 1..25 %}
  <li class="span4">
  {% set screen = '@TfptPortfolioBundle/Resources/public/images/bekic/screen' ~ i ~ '.jpg' %}
  <a href="#myModal" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal">{% image screen %}
  <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Młody Lider Innowacji" />
  {% endimage %}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

But symfony throws an error "Unexpected token "name" of value "screen"" on lane

```
<a href="#myModal" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal">{% image screen %}
```

How can i concat string to use it as asset url?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it works:

```
{% for i in 1..25 %}
  <li class="span4">
    {% set screen = 'bundles/tfptportfolio/images/bekic/screen' ~ i ~ '.jpg' %}
    <a href="#myModal" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal">
       <img src="{{ asset(screen) }}" alt="Młody Lider Innowacji" />
    </a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Obviously you must have executed the command `app/console assets:install --symlink` to create links on web directories.

**EDIT:**

Enter into a tag assetic a variable in the way you did is not possible.
To do this you must declare the variable in config.yml.

Here you can see the documentation: [documentation assetic](http://jmsyst.com/blog/asset-variables-in-assetic).

At the moment the only way is what I described above.

Comment: I found out {% image %} on the internet and it works fine. It have one advantage - doesn't require to install assets at all. But if there is no other way i need to install then :)